# Underbrace in plot label using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot some data using `pgfplots`, I currently have this code

```
\documentclass[12pt,article]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\linewidth,height=0.455\linewidth,
    title={Values},
    xlabel={Columns},
    ylabel={Values},
    xmin=0, xmax=12,
    ymin=20000, ymax=30000,
    xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12},
    ytick={20000,25000,30000},
    legend pos=north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
 ]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,23599)(1,25533.5)(2,25543)(3,25549.5)(4,25551)(5,25561)(6,25717)(7,26188)(8,26245)(9,26650)(10,26923)(11,27495)(12,27603)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Example}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this: [image]

But I want something like this:
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

Using

```
xlabel style={yshift=-20pt},
```

I moved the label for the x-axis downwards to accomodate the braces.

The braces are obtained using the `brace` decoration from the TikZ `decorations.pathreplacing` library and were placed using the `acis cs` coordinate system; the `clip=false` option was added.

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,article]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\linewidth,height=0.455\linewidth,
    title={Values},
    xlabel style={yshift=-20pt},
    xlabel={Columns},
    ylabel={Values},
    clip=false,
    xmin=0, xmax=12,
    ymin=20000, ymax=30000,
    xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12},
    ytick={20000,25000,30000},
    legend pos=north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
 ]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,23599)(1,25533.5)(2,25543)(3,25549.5)(4,25551)(5,25561)(6,25717)(7,26188)(8,26245)(9,26650)(10,26923)(11,27495)(12,27603)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Example}
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]
  ([yshift=-20pt]axis cs:0,20000) --
    node[below=3pt] {$N_1$} 
  ([yshift=-20pt]axis cs:5,20000);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]
  ([yshift=-20pt]axis cs:6,20000) --
    node[below=3pt] {$N_2$} 
  ([yshift=-20pt]axis cs:12,20000);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```